# scanmem - How to hack game boy color

Tags: process, gameboy

I have been running RetroPie on raspberry pi 2.  I am able to login (ssh) to the raspberry pi and use "scanmem" linux program to modify the values in memory (RAM) to cheat for playstation games.  Problem is that when I try to scan the memory for Game Boy Color or Super Nintendo games (processes), I am not able to find values I am looking for.  I have tried different methods.  For example, i have tried to search of decreasing/increasing values, exact values, but nothing seems to work.  How can i hack Game Boy Color and Super Nintendo games using scanmem on RetroPie?  Has anyone had any success?

Comment: Look up how GameShark did it if that's at all relevant.

Comment: good point.  i will research the idea.

Comment: romhacking.net might be useful too